# c++ interface tells me that my argument has not been declared

Tags: c++, interface

I have a generic class for many states for an automaton. It's declared as follows:

```
#ifndef STATE_H_
#define STATE_H_
#include "Automat.h"

class State {
public:
virtual void readChar(char c, Automat* automat) = 0;
virtual ~State(){};
};

#endif /* STATE_H_ */
```

I get this error in eclipse:

Multiple markers at this line

- no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘Automat* const’ to  ‘int*’
- virtual void State::readChar(char, int*)
- ‘Automat’ has not been declared

My automat is as follows:

```
    #ifndef Automat_H_
    #define Automat_H_
    #include "../../Scanner/src/IScanner.h"
    #include "./States/State.h"

    class Automat {
    public:
        int count;
        State* current;
        IScanner* scanner;
        Automat(IScanner *s);
        void readChar(char c);
        void setState(State *s);
        void error();
        ~Automat();
    };

    #endif /* Automat_H_ */
```

And finally the implementation of Automat, i will leave out some methods.

```
#include "Automat.h"
#include "./States/StartState.h"


Automat::Automat(IScanner *s) {
    current = StartState::makeStartState();
    scanner = s;
    count = 0;
}

void Automat::readChar(char c) {
    current->readChar(c, this);
}
```

I do not know what causes this. do i need to declare things in an interface? Why does it want to convert the arguments?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both headers try to include each other, which is impossible.

Luckily, neither class definition needs the full definition of the other. Each only deals with pointers to the other, for which only a declaration is needed. So replace

```
#include "Automat.h"
```

with

```
class Automat;
```

and likewise for `State`.

Answer (score -1):

IMO, I would do that preprocessor stuff in the main file, and just define in each header file one variable, so you know that it's included only once. Also you could do that in "StdAfx.h" if given.

This is just a header mess, please be sure to include it only once. `#pragma once` may help also.

Comment: StdAfx.h is only available on Windows & visual Studio - `#pragma once` is also non-Standard - but there's no Information on what platform he is: Also that wouldn't solve his problem.